# DocumentId wrapper is not working properly

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am using @DocumentId in my data struct:

```
struct UserProfile : Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
}
```

When I try to access the id I get a random string of letters (04F9C67E-C4A5-4870-9C22-F52C7F543AA5) Instead of the name of the document in firestore (GeG23o4GNJt5CrKEf3RS)

To access the documentId I am using the following code in an ObservableObject:

```
    class Authenticator: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var currentUser: UserProfile = UserProfile()
        @Published var user: String = ""    
    
        func getCurrentUser(viewModel: UsersViewModel) -> String {
            guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                return ""
            }
            
            viewModel.users.forEach { i in
                if (i.userId == userID) {
                    currentUser = i
                }
            }
                    
            print("userId \(currentUser.id ?? "no Id")")
            print("name \(currentUser.name)")
            
            return userID
        }
```

Where currentUser is a UserProfile struct. currentUser.name returns the proper value. What am I doing wrong?

currentUser is a member of an array populated using the following method:

```
func fetchData() {
    db.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.users = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserProfile? in
            
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserProfile.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did `currenetUser` come from? What created it? We can't see that here.  Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone could copy and use to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I just edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id of the UserProfile struct and the id of your data in Firestore are separate. That's why you're seeing the random string of letters.

I would change your struct similar to the below and you can just ignore the regular "id" variable when you initialize and refer to the documentID instead.

```
struct UserProfile : Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID() // ID for the struct
    var documentID: String // ID for the post in Database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overwriting the fetched DocumentID with a newly generated UUID string. You should keep it uninitialized, there is no need to set an ID manually. Even if there is, then you should set it only if the object is created from code but not if it gets decoded from Firestore

Comment: I am trying to initialize it as @DocumentId = UUID? but I'm getting a compiler error: Property type 'UUID?' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'DocumentID'

Comment: Also when I use `@DocumentId = String?` the debugger prints `userId No Id`

Comment: @seth.eeee does it print the name if it doesn't print the id or none of both?

Comment: it prints the name but not the Id

Comment: @seth.eeee that's odd and you're declaring the id the following way?: `@DocumentID var id: String?`

Comment: @seth.eeee well but the point of using `@DocumentID` is to combine them into one single attribute

Answer (score 0):

found my specific problem, I defined CodingKeys enum and when you do that, you have to make sure that you have a mapping for every attribute.

make sure you put all of your model attributes in CodingKeys enum or don't use custom CodingKeys at all

EDIT: taking the above back...it's still buggy...maybe decodes fine but not encodes and uploading

my workaround for now is to not use .adddocument but instead .setdata[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9So7a.png)